# Selenium + Chrome Webdrivers killing memory

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Each time I run my selenium script, which uses a Chrome Webdriver, I find that at the end of the execution, I have significantly (~50 Mb) less memory in my drive. I am not pulling/storing data anywhere, I am just instructing it to complete a series of clicks to navigate some UI, so why would this be happening? I suspect that is has to do with my webdrivers never actually quitting, but I'm not sure why that would be the case? If I close out of the chrome page being run by selenium prematurely, I'm assuming the driver closes too? And in the case where it does conclude running, I explicitly program the driver to quit.

Additionally, I can no longer open chrome through my desktop. It simply won't start.

Can someone give me some advice or enlighten me about what is actually taking place behind the scenes to cause this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When execution starts chromedriver creates some temp directories in this location :

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp
```

these directories starts with name like "scoped_dir8952_11195" and every directory created by chrome in temp folder starts with "scoped_dir".
when driver.quit() or close() is called it should be deleted but if it is not getting deleted then you have to delete it after execution using java code or you can simply create a .bat file that deletes the directories starting with name "scoped_dir" and then can execute it using ProcessBuilder or Runtime.exec() .
You can also manually delete them if you want.

Hope that helps you.